# Stylus : how to build var name from a variable

Tags: stylus

The last line font-size h{i} doesn't work, how can i do it ?

```
h1 = 2.441em
h2 = 1.953em
h3 = 1.563em
h4 = 1.25em
h5 = 1.25em
h6 = 1.25em

for i in (1..6)
  h{i}
    font-weight inherit
    line-height 1.2
    font-size h{i}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`font-size lookup('h' + i)` will do

see an example over here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bpamr

Comment: unfortunately there are many built-in-functions that are not documented on the homepage of this great project.